# How to remove elements from list in array without using for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this code:

```
portes = [[0, 1, 2]] * 20
bonnes_portes = np.random.choice(range(3), size=(1, 20))
premier_choix = np.random.choice(range(3), size=(1, 20))
print(portes)
print(premier_choix)
```

this outputs:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

[[1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2]]
```

I want to remove every element of `premier_choix` list from `portes` lists sequentially (remove `premier_choix[0][0]` from `portes[0][0]` ...) **without** using for loop.

Comment: How do you propose that you might remove something "sequentially" without a `for` loop of some kind? You can't vectorize this anyway because you appear to want the array dimensions to change

Comment: Something like list comprehension might be able to do this, since it has a `for` loop quality to it.

Comment: A list comprehension _is_ a `for` loop. It's not magically super-fast compared to a regular `for` loop

Comment: @Blonded a list comprehension is just a hidden and optimized for loop, that is what OP explicitly asked not to use

Comment: @pythonic833 it is not even optimized. It is merely a syntactic sugar, compiler magic.

Comment: @roganjosh @pythonic833 We don't know *really* know what he can or can't use. He says he can't use a `for` loop but he might be able to use list comprehension despite is basically being a `for` loop.

Comment: @Blonded Well we do, because they tagged this question with `numpy` and that's exactly why I mentioned "vectorization", which could be some orders of magnitude faster than a python `for` loop... should it be possible. But I don't think it is.

Comment: @roganjosh I see, it wasn't clear to me that this was for speed purposes because of the little description and my limited numpy experience.

Comment: @Blonded no worries :) When people say "avoid a `for`-loop" then they tend to want numpy vectorization. It's often predicated on some magic to make things run faster, but I could be wrong

Comment: Careful.  `portes` is a list  of lists - but given how it was constructed each of those sublists is the same thing.  If you modify one sublist you modify all.  As for avoiding loops, that's impossible with lists.  With `numpy` we do try to remove Python level loops, because that's slower than compiled whole-array tools.  But those rules don't apply to lists.

Comment: Show us what you want to do - using loops.  That will make the task clear.  Then we can suggest improvements - if possible.  Sometimes the pure list methods are better, especially if we have to factor in conversion to/from arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `np.argwhere` argument to get the relevant indices then use a slicing operation on your array and reshape it back to the desired form.

```
portes_arr = np.array(portes)
idx = np.argwhere(portes_arr != np.array(premier_choix).reshape(20,1))
portes_arr[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]].reshape(20,2)
```

(Example-)Inputs

```
premier_choix
array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

Outputs

```
portes_arr[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]].reshape(20,2)

array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I asssume there is always an element to remove (like your example above). The input:

```py
# Import
import numpy as np

# Input
portes = [[0, 1, 2]] * 20
premier_choix = np.random.choice(range(3), size=(1, 20))

# Modify input (or start with it)
portes = np.array(portes)
premier_choix = premier_choix.reshape(-1, 1)
```

A vectorized solution:

```py
output = portes[portes != premier_choix].reshape(-1, 2)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.remove()` to delete the list altogether